# My boy was born in London went to India with passport only for 2 months. Now I need to apply for his visa. Does he need to maintain fund and TB test?

Tags: uk-visa, dependent-visa

My boy was born in London. He went to India with passport only for 2 months. Now I need to apply for his visa. Does he need to maintain fund and is a TB test required while applying?

Comment: Yes. See https://www.gov.uk/uk-family-visa